# android - DPI и трудности разработки

Tags: android, дизайн

Тестировал приложение на устройстве, где `DPI` по умолчанию стоял `240`, **но** я его поменял на `160`. Тоесть, все элементы стали размером на треть меньше. Получается, приложение я проверял на "неродном" экране. Как мне теперь адаптировать его?

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос? "Помогите разобраться" в чем?  Во всей верстке на Андройде?

Comment: а что большое, маленькое?

Comment: @Nikotin N, получается, да....

Comment: @iFr0z, `TextView` на всех экранах разный. Использую dp. С `ImageView` тоже проблемы. Блин, я не могу обьяснить, как сделать нормальный дизайн?

Comment: Читайте это https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html?hl=ru  и это https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html